# Show that any non-empty interval of $\mathbb{R}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology

show that any non-empty interval of $\mathbb{R}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$

**Here's is my attempt**:

An application $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow (a,b)$ with $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ is homeomorphic $\iff$ $f$ is continuous, bijective and its inverse $f^{-1}\colon (a,b) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$  is continuous.

- I believe that in order to show that $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are continuous i just have to show that f sends $\mathbb{R}$'s opens on $(a,b)$'s opens. Which is not trivial to me. Of course $\mathbb{R}$ and $(a,b) \subset \mathbb{R}$ are both open but I don't think it implies that $f$ is open.
- It's even less trivial to me that any function of the form $f\colon\mathbb{R} \rightarrow (a,b)$ is bijective

**Edit**:

Here is an attempt to find a homeomorphic function:

$f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow (a,b)$, $f(x) = a+ \dfrac{x}{x+1}\mid{b-a}\mid $ 
But it's obviously not bijective since f(0) does not exist.

Comment: You can't just be "homeomorphic," you have to be homeomorphic *to* something. I suspect your question is actually, "Show that any non-empty interval of $\mathbb{R}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$."

Comment: Several points: You need to add what it should be homeomorphic *to*. It is called a function, not an application (I guess this was translated from French). And finally, not all functions will be homeomorphisms just because the spaces are homeomorphic, so you need to pick one.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft So If I show that $\mathbb{R}$ and $(a,b)$ are homeomorphic thanks to a specific function, they are homeomorphic?

Comment: Yes, that is what it means to be homeomorphic by definition. That a homeomorphism *exists*.

Comment: A "homeomorphism" is a certain kind of function between topological spaces. "Homeomorphic" is a binary relation amongst topological spaces, actually an equivalence relation. "$X$ and $Y$ are homeomorphic" means, by definition, "there exists a homeomorphism $f : X \to Y$".

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

For $(a,b)=(0,1)$ consider the function
$$
\varphi (0,1)\to \mathbb{R} \qquad \varphi(x)=\tan\left(\pi\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)
$$
and show that it is continuous, has range $\mathbb{R}$ and has a continuous inverse on this range (it is not so difficult).

Than use the fact that the composition of two homeomorphisms is an homeomorphism, and use 
$$
\psi (a,b) \to (0,1) \qquad \psi(x)=\frac{x-a}{b-a}
$$

so:

$$
f:(a,b) \to \mathbb{R} \qquad f(x)=\varphi(\psi(x)) =\tan\left(\pi\left(\frac{x-a}{b-a}-\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)
$$

can works.